# How to retrieve the odbc database name of tables in ms-access VBA

Tags: ms-access, odbc

I have a ms-access database and several ODBC linked tables in it.

As I have 2 set of ODBC database ,one is for production the other is for development, they have different names Development and Production.

How can I get the odbc info of the linked tables by using VBA?

Comment: What ODBC info do you need? That determines which approach is going to be the most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Using the local name of the table, you can query the MSysObjects system table (typically hidden) for the table's Foreign Name.

```
SELECT MSysObjects.ForeignName
FROM MSysObjects
WHERE (((MSysObjects.Name)="LocalTableName"));
```

If you need more information about the foreign table, try your hand at parsing the 'Connect' column from the same table.

Comment: Using system tables are officially unsupported, therefore arguably unsafe e.g. they may change in a future version. I tried this on an Access2007 ACE .accdb file and got and error, "Record(s) cannot be read; no read permission on 'MSysObjects'." Considering user level security has been removed for the .accdb format, is there a workaround at all?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you can use ODBC to connect to the .mdb file as if it were an Access database.  The linked tables will show up in that ODBC connection and be accessible at full ODBC speeds.

The nice thing about doing it that way is your program doesn't even have to know if the tables are linked tables or not.  It's nice to contain all these sysadmin-level details in a single place.

Answer (score 0):

My usual method of determining the source is to rename the tables, just like you would a native table.  I may add a suffix or prefix such as `tblTrombone_DEV` and `tblTrombone_PROD`.